# ImportError: No module named openerp

Tags: python, django, odoo

While running odoo at the first time it shows `ImportError: No module named openerp`

> C:\Python27\python.exe E:/workspaces/odoo-10.0-20170812/odoo.py -c
>
> E:\workspaces\odoo-10.0-20170812\odoo.conf Traceback (most recent call
>   last):
>
> File "E:/workspaces/odoo-10.0-20170812/odoo.py", line 160, in
>   
>       main()
>   File "E:/workspaces/odoo-10.0-20170812/odoo.py", line 156, in main
>
> import openerp
>
> ImportError: No module named openerp
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: So... do you have that dependency installed?

Comment: Yes installed...

Comment: Odoo 9 is working fine.. but odoo 10 source am getting the above error

Comment: so when u open an interactive shell with python, you can import it fine but not from inside your code? I.e. you have verified you installed dependency properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`import openerp` won't work in Odoo 10 because openerp is replaced with odoo. Upto version 9 it was openerp but in 10 it changed.

So try:

`import odoo` instead of import openerp.

Odoo 10 source code does not contain an `import openerp` anywhere, maybe you have downloaded from the wrong source.

Answer (score 1):

Odoo 10 source code does not contain the `./odoo.py` file, it is probably from `<=9.0`, where the now `odoo` module was named `openerp`. You should've got the wrong source, or mixed up the two.